Can't see grub menu in Google VM instance
I have a Google VM instance with ubuntu-minimal-2410-oracular-amd64-v20241115 image and can't seem to get the GRUB menu to display. I want to boot an ISO from the instance to test. I have tried the Shift (right and left) and Esc keys during boot but can't get the menu to display. I use the SSH in browser option(using Firefox).
I didn't see a version of GRUB. Using BIOS. Installed GRUB to /dev/sda. No errors. Ran update with no errors.
Here are the partitions of the machine.
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0     7:0    0  63.7M  1 loop /snap/core20/2434
loop1     7:1    0 374.7M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-cli/287
loop2     7:2    0  38.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21759
loop3     7:3    0 375.1M  1 loop /snap/google-cloud-cli/289
sda       8:0    0    10G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   8.9G  0 part /
├─sda13   8:13   0  1023M  0 part /boot
├─sda14   8:14   0     4M  0 part
└─sda15   8:15   0   106M  0 part /boot/efi

Results of grub-install -v:
grub-install: info: executing modprobe efivars 2>/dev/null.
grub-install: info: Looking for /sys/firmware/efi ...
grub-install: info: ...found.
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: info: cannot open `/boot/grub/device.map': No such file or directory.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 is not present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 starts from 2107392.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 is present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 starts from 2107392.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 is present.
grub-install: info: Looking for /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda is a parent of /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: /dev/sda15 starts from 2107392.
grub-install: info: opening the device hostdisk//dev/sda.
grub-install: info: drive = 0.
grub-install: warning: disk does not exist, so falling back to partition device /dev/sda15.
grub-install: info: drive = 1.
grub-install: error: disk `hostdisk//dev/sda15' not found.

Any help would be appreciated.
